# Making a choice from a list to execute

Tags: python

I have a script with 2 list stores (each with 3 choices) and want to execute the given choice.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import subprocess
import threading

class GridWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Grid Example")

        grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(grid)

        scheduler_store = Gtk.ListStore(int, str)
    scheduler_store.append([1, "noop"])
    scheduler_store.append([2, "deadline"])
    scheduler_store.append([3, "cfq"])

        label1 = Gtk.Label("Chose the Kernel to install")
        label2 = Gtk.Label("Chose scheduler to patch")

        kernel_store = Gtk.ListStore(int, str)
        kernel_store.append([1, "3.16.1"])
        kernel_store.append([2, "3.16.0"])
        kernel_store.append([3, "3.15.9"])

        button1 = Gtk.Button(label="Firefox")
        button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Morse")
        button3 = Gtk.Button(label="Clipgrab")
        #button4 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 4")
        #button5 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 5")
        #button6 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 6")

    combobox1 = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=2)
        scheduler_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry(scheduler_store)
        #scheduler_combo.connect("changed", self.on_scheduler_combo_changed)
        scheduler_combo.set_entry_text_column(1)
        combobox1.pack_start(scheduler_combo, False, False, 0)

    combobox2 = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=2)
        kernel_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry(kernel_store)
        kernel_combo.connect("changed", self.on_kernel_combo_changed)
        kernel_combo.set_entry_text_column(1)
        combobox2.pack_start(kernel_combo, False, False, 0)

        grid.add(button1)
        grid.attach(button2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        grid.attach_next_to(button3, button2, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1, 1)
        grid.attach_next_to(label2, button2, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1)
        grid.attach_next_to(combobox1, label2, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1, 1)
        grid.attach_next_to(label1, label2, Gtk.PositionType. RIGHT, 1, 1)
        grid.attach_next_to(combobox2, label1, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1, 1)

        #grid.attach_next_to(button4, button3, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 2, 1)
        #grid.attach(button5, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        #grid.attach_next_to(button6, button5, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1)

    def on_kernel_combo_changed(self,combo):
        tree_iter = combo.get_active_iter()
        if tree_iter != None:
            model = combo.get_model()
            row_id, name = model[tree_iter][:2]
            print("Selected: ID=%d, name=%s" % (row_id, name))
            if  == 1:
          def my_thread(obj):
        cmd = "apt-get install morse"
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        while True:
          line = proc.stdout.read(2)
          if not line:
            break
          threading.Thread(target=my_thread, args=(self,)).start()

        else:
            entry = combo.get_child()
            print("Entered: %s" % entry.get_text())

win = GridWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I tried:

```
if %d == 1:
```

which does not work.

```
if kernel_store.append([1, "3.16.1"]) == 1
```

doesn't work either, and

```
if Selected: ID=%d == 1:
```

does not work either.

It should read what the user chooses (it does) but then it should start a function. I can't implement the latter part. Ideas?

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere do you assign `%d = ...` (you can't, it's not a valid name), so why on earth would you expect `if %d == 1:` to get you anywhere?

[`ListStore.append`](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkliststore.html#method-gtkliststore--append) returns a `TreeIter`, so `if kernel_store.append([1, "3.16.1"]) == 1` will never evaluate `True`.

It starts to make some vague sense with your third attempt, which on the face of it is the worst:

```
if Selected: ID=%d == 1:
```

`Selected` is never assigned (although unlike `%d`, it could be) and the second part is a `SyntaxError` for about three reasons, but it looks like you're trying to get *the value taken by the `%d` token*. The line:

```
print("Selected: ID=%d, name=%s" % (row_id, name))
```

creates a new string (e.g. `"Selected: ID=42, name=Douglas"`), passes it to the `print` function, then discards it. The string is not assigned to any name, so it is inaccessible after this line. Even if the string was accessible, something like:

```
s = "Selected: ID=%d, name=%s" % (row_id, name)
print(s)
```

it would make no sense to try to extract the values back out from it when **you already have access to them**:

```
if row_id == 1:
```